# How do I skip specified symbols while parsing

Tags: parsing, haskell, trifecta

I am trying to write a [trifecta](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta) parser that can parse all three of the phone numbers below. When I try to use `parsePhone` by calling `parseString parsePhone mempty phoneNum2`, the parser fails at the first dash and says it expected `'('`.

When I call the parser on phoneNum1 it fails at `')'` , saying it expected `'('`.

Why is my skipSymbol parser failing? I would think that due to my use of `<|>`, the parser would be fine with not detecting `'('` and move on. Is the technique that I am attempting with `skipSymbol` bound to fail?

```
phoneNum1 = "(123) 456 7890"
phoneNum2 = "123-456-7890"
phoneNum3 = "1234567890"

type NumberingPlanArea = Integer
type Exchange = Integer
type LineNumber = Integer

data PhoneNumber =
  PhoneNumber NumberingPlanArea
              Exchange LineNumber
  deriving (Eq, Show)

parse3digits :: Parser Integer
parse3digits = read <$> replicateM 3 digit

skipSymbol :: Parser ()
skipSymbol =
      skipMany (char '(')
  <|> skipMany (char ')')
  <|> skipMany (char '-')
  <|> skipMany (char ' ')

parsePhone :: Parser PhoneNumber
parsePhone =
  skipSymbol >>
  parse3digits >>=
    \area -> skipSymbol >>
    parse3digits >>=
      \exch -> skipSymbol >>
      integer >>=
        \line ->
          pure $ PhoneNumber area exch line
```

Comment: What parser-combinator library is that you're using?

Comment: [trifecta](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta)

Comment: Does `skipSymbol = skipMany (char '(' <|> char ')' <|> ...)` fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skipMany p` applies the parser `p` zero-or-more times. Operationally, it goes something like this:

1. Attempt to apply `p`.
2. If `p` succeeded, repeat step 1.
3. If `p` failed without consuming input, succeed and return `()`. (This is what the “zero” in “zero-or-more” means.)
4. If `p` failed after consuming some input, report the failure.

Let's look at how `skipSymbol` operates on the input `)`.

1. Parsec tries the left hand choice of `skipSymbol`, namely `skipMany (char '(')`.
2. `skipMany (char '(')` attempts to apply `char '('`, which fails without consuming input because the input character is `)`.
3. Because `char '('` failed without consuming input, `skipMany (char '(')` **succeeds** without consuming input. This means the other choices in `skipSymbol` won't be attempted.
4. The current input character is still `)` (which is what causes `parse3Digits` to later fail).

As noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62389025/how-do-i-skip-specified-symbols-while-parsing/62391839#comment110344198_62389025), the fix is to change the definition of `skipSymbol` to

```
skipSymbol :: Parser ()
skipSymbol = skipMany $ choice [char c | c <- "()- "]
```

This version loops a choice, rather than choosing between loops.